# Where can I find web databases for my big data project?

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-studio, sql, azure

I started a new course at Microsoft to learn more about working with Azure, Visual Studio, SQL and Excel and I want to have a few sites I can use to pull the data from.

It helps if the site keeps the data up to date and it has to be publicly available data because I don't want to do anything wrong that violates any privacy laws.

If you know any can you share it with me please?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to see http://opendata.stackexchange.com

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score -1):

If you just want a database that you can use for learning/practicing with SQL Server, you can [download the AdventureWorks database](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49502).

Comment: 1) this question is off-topic (asking for generic database recommendations). And 2) AdventureWorks is a reference database for relational content. Not really helpful at all when trying to learn Big Data concepts.